Edit the Add to Cart button in Shopify
I want to edit the code for the Add to Cart button on the product page in Shopify. Instead of just adding the product to the cart, I want the system to add the product to the cart and then redirect to Shopify's checkout page after clicking the Add to Cart button.
I want to change the code to fix that button instead of installing the app

Add this to your product.liquid or product-template.liquid file. It will redirect to checkout immediately after adding to cart.
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const addToCartForm = document.querySelector('form[action="/cart/add"]');
    
    if (addToCartForm) {
      addToCartForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        fetch('/cart/add.js', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify(FormData(addToCartForm))
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          window.location.href = '/checkout';
        });
      });
    }
  });
</script>

